# Uncaught TypeError: data.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to convert the model instances into a JSON object and then according to the value selected in the dropdown menu, I want to assign its amount to the `line_one_unit_price` text field in the form.

Javascript code:

```
{{ data|json_script:"hello-data" }}
<script type="text/javascript">
    const data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);

    document.getElementById('id_line_one').onchange = function(event){
    let elementInData = data.find(() => item.pk == event.target.value);
    document.getElementById('id_line_one_unit_price').value = elementInData && elementInData.amount ? elementInData.amount : 0;
};

</script>
```

I guess, I am getting the error at `data.find` because `.find` is used on an array whereas the constant `data` is not an array? How do I convert that JSON object into an array? how do I assign the amount of the `title` selected in the forms to the `line_one_unit_price`?

[image: ss]

When I click some title from the dropdown, I want the amount to be displayed in the `Unit Price`.

`views.py`:

```
def add_invoice(request):
  form = InvoiceForm(request.POST or None)
  data = serializers.serialize("json", Inventory.objects.all())
  total_invoices = Invoice.objects.count()
  queryset = Invoice.objects.order_by('-invoice_date')[:6]

  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Successfully Saved')
    return redirect('/invoice/list_invoice')
  context = {
    "form": form,
    "title": "New Invoice",
    "total_invoices": total_invoices,
    "queryset": queryset,
    "data": data,
  }
  return render(request, "entry.html", context)
```

`models.py`:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
  product_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  product = models.TextField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
  title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=120, default='', blank=True, unique=True)
  amount = models.IntegerField('Unit Price', default=0, blank=True, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try not to use serializer, just send inventory objecs purely to the context

Comment: @kazemqanati Can you please demonstrate it with the code I mentioned? How can I access the `inventory objects` in the HTML file and then assign the amount etc?